# Genetic Algorithm Java

Tags: java, genetic-algorithm

Can someone tell me why i am getting two different vales of `best` just before and after `crossover`. I am not altering the `pop` anywhere before it.

```
public void generateNewPopulation() {
  numRuns++;

  ArrayList<Pair> Copy = new ArrayList<Pair>();
  Copy.addAll(pop); //pop is global initialized earlier
  System.out.println("Copy population before - " + numRuns);

  Pair best = getMax(pop);
  System.out.println(best.getX() + " " + best.getY()); //1st value of best obtained
  popClone.add(best);
  popClone.addAll(rouletteWheel(Copy));

  ArrayList<Pair> Clone = new ArrayList<Pair>();
  Clone.addAll(popClone);

  for (int u = 0; u < 4; u++) {
    int randNo1, randNo2;
    do {
      randNo1 = rand.nextInt(8) + 1;
      randNo2 = rand.nextInt(8) + 1;
    } while (randNo1 == randNo2);
    ArrayList<Pair> a = crossover(popClone.get(rand1), popClone.get(rand2));
    popClone.set(rand1, a.get(0));
    popClone.set(randNo2, a.get(1));
  }

  System.out.println(best.getX() + " " + best.getY()); // 2nd value of best
}

pop.clear();
popClone.add(best);  
pop.addAll(popClone); 
popClone.clear();
```

`crossover` is as follows

```
public ArrayList<Pair> crossover(Pair x, Pair y) {
  ArrayList<Pair> pai = new ArrayList<Pair>();
  int randNo1;
  int randNo2;
  int random = rand.nextInt(8) + 1;
  char swap;
  for (int i = random; i < 10; i++) {
    swap = x.getX().charAt(i);
    char y1 = y.getX().charAt(i);
    x.getX().setCharAt(i, y1);
    y.getX().setCharAt(i, swap);
  }

  for (int i = random; i < 10; i++) {
    char swap2;
    swap2 = x.getY().charAt(i);
    char y2 = y.getY().charAt(i);
    x.getY().setCharAt(i, y2);
    y.getY().setCharAt(i, swap2);
  }
  pai.add(x);
  pai.add(y);

  return pai;
}
```

This is the `getMax`

```
public Pair getMax(ArrayList<Pair> p) {
  int maxIndex = 0;
  double fitnessValue;
  double maxValue =
      decodedVal(p.get(maxIndex)); //decodedVal gets the fitness value of corresponding chromosome

  for (int i = 0; i < p.size(); i++) {
    fitnessValue = decodedVal(p.get(i));
    if (fitnessValue > maxValue) {
      maxValue = fitnessValue;
      maxIndex = i;
    } else ;
  }
  return p.get(maxIndex);
}
```

Comment: The copy of ```pop``` you're making is not really a copy, both lists will reference the same group of objects. i.e. it is not a deep-copy

Comment: I guess this is more appropriate in Artificial Intelligence Stack Exchange http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93481/artificial-intelligence?referrer=ZmhvdPpNkK4uGj6x_HIV1w2. Unfortunately its still in Commitment stage.